# Grid Lines wont show

Tags: c#, wpf

Grid lines wont show on runt-time I can seem to see where I am going wrong. This is a WPF window application. I just want to generate columns and rows using C# code. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Windows;
      using System.Windows.Controls;
      using System.Windows.Data;
      using System.Windows.Documents;
      using System.Windows.Input;
      using System.Windows.Media;
      using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
      using System.Windows.Navigation;
      using System.Windows.Shapes;

      namespace generator
       {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void CreateGrid()
    {

        ColumnDefinition myColum =new ColumnDefinition();
        RowDefinition myRow = new RowDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition myColum1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        RowDefinition myRow1 = new RowDefinition();

        Grid myGrid = new Grid();
        myRow.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        myColum.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        myRow1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        myColum1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(myColum);
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(myRow);
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(myColum1);
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(myRow1);
        myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateGrid();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Because its easier to dynamically render objects with c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question may as well read "Grid won't show".

You are creating a new `Grid` instance, but you never add it to the visual tree. You may assign it to the Window's `Content` property:

```
private void CreateGrid()
{
    ...
    Content = myGrid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! what is the visual tree?